# How can I return a value from php to java?

Tags: java, php, android

I have a table Info as image below

[image]

The id is set to auto-increment. When the addInformation get called, it will insert data to Information.

```
 addInformation(name, weather, date2, status, first1[1], last1[1]);
```

**AddInformation function**

```
 public void addInformation(final String name, final String weather, final String date2, final String status, final String timeIn, final String timeOut) {
        class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(WorkDetailsTable.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //addWorkForce(Sub, NoP, NoH, Long.parseLong(s));
               // addWorkDetails(results, Long.parseLong(s));
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put(Config.KEY_USER_NAME, name);
                data.put(Config.KEY_WEATHER, weather);
                data.put(Config.KEY_DATE, date2);
                data.put(Config.KEY_STATUS, status);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEIN, timeIn);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TIMEOUT, timeOut);
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.ADD_INFORMATION, data);
                String response=? // get last Id from php
                return result;
            }
        }

        AddInfo ru = new AddInfo();
        ru.execute(name, weather, date2, status, timeIn, timeOut);
    }
```

I'm new in php and now trying to get the lastID from table Info and return the value to android. But I get undefined index.

```
   <?php

    class AddInformation{


       function response(){
          /** @var mysqli $con */
          require_once('dbConnect.php'); //$con = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'so');
          $name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
          $weather = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['weather']);
          $date = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
          $status = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
          $timein = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['timeIn']);
          $timeout = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['timeOut']);
          $con->query("INSERT INTO information (name, weather, date, status, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('$name', '$weather', '$date', $status', '$timeIn', '$timeOut')");
          echo $con->insert_id;
       }
    }

    $ai = new AddInformation();
    $ai->response();
?>
```

> 1. How to return last ID from php (insert into LastId) to response(java) /
> 2. How to solve undefined index in php ?

Can someone help me ? Appreciated.

Comment: You should use MySQLi's [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) seeing as you are using MySQLi.

Comment: @Script47 It can return the value to java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by not working so hard, use PDO and prepared statements rather than mysqli and sanitizing the data yourself.

It's been awhile since I used mysqli, but $con->insert_id should work, unless there's an error.

Did the insert work?

Do this.

```
if (!$con->query("INSERT INTO information (name, weather, date, status, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('$name', '$weather', '$date', $status', '$timeIn', '$timeOut')")) {
    printf("Error message: %s\n", $con->error);
    exit;
}
return $con->insert_id;
```

Then in your executing code.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');    
echo json_encode($ai->response());
```

Now you're returning the insert id via a web service to Java.

Then in your Java decode the json response.

If you're getting an undefined on the insert_id call, then your insert didn't work correctly.